# Which version of hibernate support jpa 2.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, version

Currently I am using `JPA 2.0` with `hibernate 3.6` . I tried to search but couldn't find, can anyone list out `JPA 2.1` is supported by which versions of hibernate?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [Hibernate's versions list](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/), JPA 2.1 is going to be supported by version 4.3 or by 5.0

Comment: thats sad to here. And I think hibernate 4.2 is yet to be released right?

Comment: The versions list mentions JPA 2.1 being supported from 4.3.0.Beta1 onward. Hibernate 4.2.0 can't be supporting JPA 2.1 as it was released in March 2013 and JPA 2.1 was finalised after that in April 2013

Answer (score 31):

Hibernate 4.3.0.Final (Dec. 16, 2013) is the first production ready release to support jpa 2.1.

See: http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateORM430FinalRelease

> The main focus of 4.3 was JPA 2.1 support, so much of the work these
>   past few months focused on new JPA 2.1 features.

Answer (score 7):

Boris is right though you can try using,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

in your `pom.xml` switching to the Hibernate 4.3.x or Hibernate 5.x.

Comment: Is it something like nightly/dev builds?

Comment: It is a dev build. You can look at all the resources (maybe with the exception of the mentioned readme file I couldn't find right now) on grepcode: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Draft-7plus

Comment: do u have any idean about whether jpa 2.1 is released or whats release plans?

Comment: what do you mean with `jpa 2.1 is released'?` Jpa is just a specification, then there are several implementation. Here: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aroadmap-panel you can read the full road map of Hibernate, and their implementation (`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`) looks to be at a good point, with 124 over 140 issues resolved. But an exact date is hard to says, as they state `JPA 2.1 support; may be released as 4.2 or wrapped into 5.0 depending on timing`

Comment: oh yeah , So by released i mean JPA 2.1 specs are not finalised and release right? And may be hibernate guys would be working in parallel to jpa 2.1 specs. right?

Comment: So, [JPA 2.1 Specs](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) are actually in `Public Reviews Ballot`, which is going to end the 4th of February. According to [Spec Lead Guide](http://jcp.org/en/resources/guide), which describes the process of release a spec, there are at least two more months to wait, but the duration of the `Proposed Final Draft` stage is not indicated. I guess Hibernate team is working in parallel, since spec are not likely to change that much from now on.

Comment: Funny fact, there's a project I worked on that's using this dependency for like 2 years now. And it's one of the most important company projects.