# Which version of Spring Data supports JPA 2.1?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I googled, but was not able to find this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data 2.0.2 supports Hibernate 5.2 and this is an implementation of JPA 2.1

Comment: Simon, based on my research Hibernate 4.3.x start supports JPA 2.1. Is it true? If true, then do you know what the first version of Spring Data is that supports JPA 2.1? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558931/which-version-of-hibernate-support-jpa-2-1

Comment: I would 2 becuase Spring Data 1 is Hibernate 3.6. But search yourself http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.data%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-data-jpa%22

Comment: Simon, do you happen to know whether I should add this dependency to use JPA 2.1? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final  Thanks!